# Deleting a db entry from datagrid that is tied via two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to develop a php/mysql job system for my own use, i have limited php knowledge but have followed tutorials etc and grasp the basics.

My database is made up of relational tables using FK etc, job details are kept in Jobs table, parts for the job are kept in Parts table and the two are linked via the job_parts table.

my current page displays all the data needed for a job (parts, customer details, costings etc)

i have a segment of my page that is designated to parts which pulls and echo's db rows from the following query and code:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['id']))  
        {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT part_name, part_cost, part_rrp, quantity FROM jobs INNER JOIN job_parts USING (job_id) 
            INNER JOIN parts USING (part_id) Where job_id = '$id'");
        echo "<div class='divTable'>
                <div class='divTableBody'>
                <div class='divTableRow'>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Part Name</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Qty</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Cost Price</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Cost Total</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Retail Price</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'>Total</div>
                    <div class='divTableHead'></div>
                                        </div>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {   
            $costTotal = $row['1'] * $row['3'];
            $rrpTotal = $row['2'] * $row['3'];

                echo "<div class='divTableRow'>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>" . $row['0'] . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>". $row['3'] . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($costTotal, 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($row['1'], 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" . number_format($row['2'], 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>&pound;" .number_format($rrpTotal, 2) . "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='divTableCell'>
                            <a href=''>Edit</a> 
                            <a href=''> Delete</a></div>";
                    echo "</div>";      
            }   
            echo "</div></div>";
        }else
        {
            echo "<H1><b><em>No ID is set so there is no data to get!</em></b></H1>";
        }

        ?>
```

I am struggling to work out how to delete a specific db entry from both the parts and job_parts database table.

any help would be appreciated, or pointing me in the right direction as i have searched stackoverflow and several other forums but to no avail.

Table structure:
[imageTS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhoc.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code, used for deletion process?

Comment: thats where i am struggling, as i need it to complete it within the page not via an external page and i am struggling to grasp

Comment: Does you have anything same in all table like `id` ? You can used that id for deleting all entry in both table

Comment: db structure added to main post

Comment: So you can use **part_id** to delete row from both table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a delete join to delete data from the job_parts table first, followed by the parts table

```
$delQuery = "DELETE FROM job_parts, parts
INNER JOIN parts ON parts.part_id = job_parts.part_id
WHERE parts.part_id = '$part_id'";
```

For more Information, please take some time to read through [MySQL Delete Join Article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am yet to try the query but the Article really helped put what i thought was a very complicated problem into simple terms.